# error using sqlite3 with Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have Ruby 2.2.2p95 on Windows.  I am not using Rails.  I am able to use the following to install sqlite3

```
gem install sqlite3
```

When I crate a Ruby file as follows, it fails to load sqlite3:

**test.rb**

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'sqlite3',
  :database => 'test.db'
)
```

When I run

```
ruby test.rb
```

it throws an error from the line where I have the require statement for sqlite3:

```
cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

I have sqlite installed on Windows and was able to create a table in the database.  Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: Check version of your sqlite! Probably, they differ

Comment: looks like there's an issue open, but no answer yet: https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/160